# div:before / after interfering with other divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS :before and :after to add dotted line visual elements to a div:

[image]

But it seems to be interfering with the 'edit' button elements. (the edit button won't respond to any onClick or MouseOver or Hover events while the parent div's :before and :after CSS are there) Any ideas how to render the button element 'in front of' the :before and :after elements, aside from Z-index?

CSS:

```
.window_header{
    width:600px;
    height:42px;
    background: #333 url("../img/bg-2.png") repeat;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),inset 0 -4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),inset 1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),inset -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),inset 0 2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15),inset -2px 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15),inset 2px 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.window_header:before,
.window_header:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 562px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:1;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
    background:-webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 260, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
}

.button_edit{
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    border-radius:6px;
    width:70px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.496094);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index:100;
}

.fl_right{
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="window_header">
    <div class="button_edit fl_right" id="button_edit_site"> Edit </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant CSS code(`.pattern_dmd`, `.shadow`, `.fl_right`), because I tried with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TsLva/) and seem to work normally.

Comment: @Fong-WanChau, code updated (thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `position: relative` to `.button_edit`. `z-index` requires `relative`/`absolute` to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/CB2BE/1/

```
.button_edit{
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: @BenBernards Hm, I think there only `.window_header` need `position: relative`, all other element just let it natural and they are going to be fine. (I added style to the button because Ben did not posted it...) See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TsLva/3/